RegionDimension Precision
RegionDimension[ImplicitRegion[x^2 + y^2 <= 26 && y == Sqrt[27], {x, y}]] outputs -Inf, meaning that there region is empty.
RegionDimension[ImplicitRegion[x^2 + y^2 <= 26 && y == Sqrt[26], {x, y}]] outputs 0, meaning that there is some points of intersection.
But what if I have only an approximate value of Sqrt[26]? I want RegionDimension[ImplicitRegion[x^2 + y^2 <= 26 && y == 5.090195, {x, y}]] outputs 0 instead of 1. Is there Precision option?
What I want to do is to determine whether line x=a touches the circle x^2 + y^2 <= 26, but a can be both exact and decimal.

Why not use RegionDisjoint? E.g. RegionDisjoint[ImplicitRegion[x^2 + y^2 <= 26, {x, y}], ImplicitRegion[y == 5.090195, {x, y}]]

According to my requirements RegionDisjoint[ImplicitRegion[x^2 + y^2 <= 26, {x, y}],   ImplicitRegion[y == Sqrt[26] + 10^-7, {x, y}]] should give False.

Why should it be False? The line doesn't touch the circle.

@CarlWoll, because I want to decrease precision.

Which version are you using? RegionDimension[  ImplicitRegion[x^2 + y^2 <= 26 && y == 5.090195, {x, y}]] gives me a 1. I am using v12.2.0.

MMA version 14.1 outputs 1.

rgnDim[a_, r_ : Sqrt[26]] := RegionDimension[ImplicitRegion[x^2 + y^2 <= r^2 && y == Rationalize[a, 0], {x, y}]]; rgnDim[5.090195]

Maybe RegionMeasure. Table[RegionMeasure[    ImplicitRegion[x^2 + y^2 <= 26 && y == Sqrt[26] - 10^-7, {x, y}]] <    10^-k, {k, 0, 7}]
